# PubSub - Most efficient way to publish video frames?

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a service that generates several frames from a video source (using OpenCV)

I'm next encoding these frames into bytes string and publishing them as a batch through Pub/Sub

```
# Encoding each (opencv) frame
 _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)

 pub_sub.publish(buffer.tobytes())


# PubSub class
class PubSub(object):
        def __init__(self, project_id='xxx', topic_name='xxx'):
            self.publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(
                    pubsub_v1.types.BatchSettings(max_latency=1)
            )
            self.topic_path = self.publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)

        def publish(self, frame_as_bytes):
            future = self.publisher.publish(self.topic_path, data=frame_as_bytes)
            print(future.result())
            print('Published messages with batch settings.')
```

My bytes frames = around 300kb data

But the latency is very huge here, how can I improve these operations?

**Update**:

Well, it seems the opencv encoding operation is costly:

```
_, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
```

I'm running the program on my laptop so I believe this will not be a problem with a VM with more CPU.

I've added these lines to reduce image weight before encoding:

```
frame = frame_helper.rescale_frame(frame, scale_percent=40)
encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 80]
```

And this is way faster now.

I'll do another test with a bigger machine.

Comment: did you identify where the latency come from? Is it the encoding? the sending?

Comment: Edit: the latency comes from the frame encoding via OpenCV. So I believe this is because I'm running that on my laptop. Gonna check with a higher config.